# Codimension of ideals in polynomial rings over PIDs

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $R$ be a (commutative) principal ideal domain and let $J$ be an ideal in $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Is it possible to make a general statement about the codimension (=rank/height) of $J$?

As $J$ does not have to be prime, by codimension I mean the minimum of the codimensions of all the prime ideals containing $J$.

Thanks!

Comment: first of all, thanks for editing! Unfortunatly I don't have any expectations or intuitions about the height because I have never worked with it so far. I am working on a  proposititon about commutative noetherian rings of Krull dimension $d$ and wanted to apply it on PIDs (which have Krull dimension $1$). The proof of the theorem contains demands on the height (height(J)>d). So I hoped there exist statements about the height of ideals over polynomial rings because I coud't find any...

Comment: Note: Since $R[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$ is Noetherian, the phrase "finitely generated" to refer to its ideal $J$ is superfluous.